# Share page to external users via Notion api

Tags: c#, .net, notion-api, notion.net

I'm trying to use [Notion api](https://developers.notion.com/) and [Notion SDK for .Net](https://github.com/notion-dotnet/notion-sdk-net) to share some pages to external users by email. There is a [People property](https://developers.notion.com/reference/property-item-object#people-property-values) in `Page` object. But I get an error if I try to add this property to an existing page:

```
var page = await client.Pages.RetrieveAsync(myPageId);
page.Properties.Add("people", new PeoplePropertyValue() {Id = "Owners", People = users.Results});
await client.Pages.UpdatePropertiesAsync(myPageId, page.Properties);
```

Error message for pages with database parent object:

```
Notion.Client.NotionApiException : people is not a property that exists.
Data:
  StatusCode: BadRequest
  NotionApiErrorCode: InvalidJSON
   at Notion.Client.RestClient.SendAsync(String requestUri, HttpMethod httpMethod, IDictionary`2 queryParams, IDictionary`2 headers, Action`1 attachContent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Error message for pages with page parent object:

```
Notion.Client.NotionApiException : body failed validation. Fix one:
body.parent.database_id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.properties.people should be not present, instead was `{"type":"people","people":[{"object":"user","id":"39636...`.
Data:
  StatusCode: BadRequest
  NotionApiErrorCode: InvalidJSON
   at Notion.Client.RestClient.SendAsync(String requestUri, HttpMethod httpMethod, IDictionary`2 queryParams, IDictionary`2 headers, Action`1 attachContent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I also tried to create a new page with people property but I had the same error message.

```
await client.Pages.CreateAsync(new PagesCreateParameters()
    {
        Cover = new ExternalFile()
        {
            External = new ExternalFile.Info { Url = coverUrlString }
        },
        Children = new List<IBlock>
        {
            new QuoteBlock
            {
                Quote = new QuoteBlock.Info
                    { Text = new[] { new RichTextText() { Text = new Text() { Content = pageContentText } } } }
            }
        },
        Icon = new EmojiObject { Emoji = "" },
        Parent = new ParentPageInput { PageId = parentPageId }, // or ParentDataBaseInput
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyValue>
        {
            ["title"] = new TitlePropertyValue {Id = "KpQq", Title = new List<RichTextBase>() {new RichTextText(){ Text = new Text() { Content = pageTitleText } }}},
            ["people"] = new PeoplePropertyValue()
            {
                Id = "Owners",
                People = users.Results
            }
        }
    });
```

I also tried to use [Notion-Sharp](https://github.com/BusHero/Notion-Sharp) with same result:

```
INotion client2 = Notion.Notion.NewClient(bearerToken);
await client2.CreatePageAsync(new Page()
{
    Cover = new File.External { Uri = new Uri(coverUriText) },
    Parent = new Parent.Database() {Id = Guid.Parse(parentDatabaseIdText)},
    Properties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyValue>
    {
        ["title"] = new PropertyValue.Title 
            { Id = "Title", Name = "MyTitle", Content = new []{new RichText.Text() {Content = titleText}}},
        ["people"] = new PropertyValue.People
        {
            Id = "Owners",
            Value = new[] { new User.Person { Email = myUserEmail } }
        }
    }
});
```

Error message with database parent object:

```
Notion.NotionException : people is not a property that exists.
```

Error message with page parent object:

```
Notion.NotionException : body failed validation. Fix one:
body.parent.database_id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.properties.people should be not present
```

Is there a way to share a page to an external user in notion api? Is there a way to change read and write rights for a page to an existing workspace user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with the current public API.

You can use their [SCIM endpoint](https://www.notion.so/help/provision-users-and-groups-with-scim) to add Groups, add *Members*, and add Members to Groups (which can be used to facilitate access), but there is not a way to grant access to a specific Page via email of Member. This is also only available on the Enterprise plan.

Guests cannot be added to Groups so your ask is a non-starter for now, unless you want to use private APIs which could theoretically get you banned.